# Calling configure and make from Perl script

Tags: perl, ipc

I need help please. I'm writing a Perl script to configure, compile and install MPICH. The initial two tasks require calling `configure` and `make` commands. I'm struggling to pass the options to `configure` command. Please find my minimal example below:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use v5.38;
use autodie;
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::System::Simple qw(capturex);

# Writes text into given file
sub writef($fname, $txt) {
    open  my $fh, ">:encoding(UTF-8)", $fname;
    print $fh $txt;
    close $fh;
}

my $gnubin ='/opt/local/bin';
my $prefix ='/opt/mpich-4.1.2';
my $np     = 8;
my $txt;

print "Setting environment variables...\n";

$ENV{'FC'}  = $gnubin . '/gfortran';
$ENV{'F77'} = $ENV{'FC'};
$ENV{'CC'}  = $gnubin . '/gcc';
$ENV{'CXX'} = $gnubin . '/g++';

$ENV{'FFLAGS'} = '-m64 -fallow-argument-mismatch';
$ENV{'CFLAGS'} = '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -m64';

mkdir 'build';
chdir 'build';

print "Configuring MPICH...\n";
my $conf_options = "--prefix=$prefix --enable-shared=no --enable-fast=O3,ndebug --disable-error-checking --enable-fortran=all --enable-cxx --disable-opencl --enable-romio --without-timing --without-mpit-pvars";
$txt = capturex('../configure', $conf_options);
&writef('c.txt', $txt);

print "Compiling MPICH...\n";
$txt = capturex('make', '-j', $np);
&writef('m.txt', $txt);
```

Configuration is done correctly, but compilation fails with the following error messages:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '--without-timing'
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '--without-mpit-pvars/etc"'
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '--without-mpit-pvars/lib/libfabric"'
```

It seems I have a problem in the `capturex` call. I suspect there are no spaces in between the `$conf_options` when they are passed to `capturex` command. I tried declaring configure options as an array `my @conf_options` and passing the strings in the `qq()` operator. But that fails with a similar set of errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should look at the compilation line that make is running that gives you those errors, and/or edit your question and provide it here.  I don't know where those arguments are coming from but none of them are valid GCC options, so I'm not surprised you see those errors.  You'll need to figure out how and why they are being added to the compile line.

Comment: Yes, I will do that! That means replacing `capturex` with `systemx` for now.

Comment: Tip: [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper)'s `write_text` is a drop-in replacement for `writef`, and it provides error checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing arguments, you are passing part of a shell command to a sub that doesn't invoke a shell.

Replace

```perl
my $conf_options = "--prefix=$prefix --enable-shared=no ...";
my $txt = capturex( "../configure", $conf_options );
```

with

```perl
my @conf_options = ( "--prefix=$prefix", "--enable-shared=no", "..." );
my $txt = capturex( "../configure", @conf_options );
```

or

```perl
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $prefix_lit = shell_quote( $prefix );

my $conf_options = "--prefix=$prefix_lit --enable-shared=no ...";
my $txt = capture( "../configure $conf_options" );
```

The former doesn't use a shell, while the latter does.

Comment: May I please ask, is your first suggestion equivalent to `my @conf_options = qq(--prefix=$prefix --enable-shared=no)` etc.?

Comment: No. `qq` produces a single string. That would be identical to your original code, which is equivalent to the shell command `../configure '--prefix=/opt/local/bin --enable-shared=no ...'`

Comment: May I please ask, is there a shorter way to express this list of options, that would eliminate the need to explicitly write the double quotes for each option and follow it with a comma?

Comment: Since most are fixed and don't contains spaces, you could use `my @conf_options = ( "--prefix=$prefix", qw( --enable-shared=no ... ) );`.

Comment: I just noticed you want to save the output to a file. And that you fail to save stderr (which is arguably the most valuable). I'd use IPC::Run instead of `capturex` for that. (You'd have the same problem and solution, though.) I'll update later today if I can.

Comment: I have been thinking to use [IO::Tee](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Tee) module to both save the STDOUT and STDERR into a log file and see command output on my screen. Currently, I don't see, what `configure` and `make` do.

Answer (score 3):

`capturex` takes a list of options to pass to the command. If you put all the options in a string and pass only that string, then that string is the single option to the command. Any calls to `capturex` with multiple arguments will bypass the shell, so the shell does not have any chance to break up your single string into separate arguments. You can see this in the doc examples for [IPC::System::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple).

Comment: How do I pass configure options in an elegant way? Do I do it as @ikegami suggests?

Comment: You can do it as the docs show you, or the way ikegami suggests. They are the same thing. FWIW, you will almost never go wrong doing it the way ikegami suggests no matter the question.

Comment: I read the documentation to [IPC::System::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple) and looked at examples. I see, that arguments to `capture` are passed in an array variable `@args`. But how this array variable is defined is omitted from the description. It seems I tripped over something basic.